# Viewing live streaming of security cameras attached to PC

Tags: video, streaming

How can I stream security cameras installed on my PC so that I can watch them anywhere the internet is available?

I have standard security cameras and can watch up to all four of them at the same time on my computer.

But I would like to be able to view the stream and follow the images and video online away from the computer.

Is this possible?

Comment: What camera? What monitoring software? Are you wanting to leave a computer on all the time?

Answer (score 1):

Simple trick, you can access your PC from anywhere using [logmein](http://www.logmein.com) and see the camera stream.

Comment: it is good method but I need a better solution... please..